# Is there a way to convert API data to a Mapbox layer?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mapbox, layer, mapbox-gl-js

I have a callback function below that is able to generate data from the Eventbrite API. Currently this function can generate markers on my Mapbox map through the 'new Marker' method. However instead of a marker, I want to generate this data into layers on the map through the 'Mapbox addLayer' method.

```
    callbackEventbrite(function(result){
    const keys = Object.values(result);
    for(const key of keys){
        geojson = {
            type: 'featureCollection',
            features: [{
                type: 'feature',
                geometry: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [key.venue.longitude, key.venue.latitude]
                }
            }]
        }
        eventInfo.push(
            {"longitude": key.venue.longitude , "latitude": key.venue.latitude , "name": key.name.text, "venue": key.venue.name, "date": key.start.local, "category": key.category_id}
        );
    }
});
```

I basically want to this , which generates symbols on the map, based on the coordinates of the geometry, but with the API data instead.

```
map.addLayer({
        "id": "locations",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": {
            "type": "geojson",
            "data": {
                "type": "FeatureCollection",
                "features": [
                    {
                      "type": "Feature",
                      "properties": {
                        "Title": "The Congress Inn",
                        "Description": "Pub located in Longton",
                        "Type": "Pub",
                        "Address": "14 Sutherland Rd, Stoke-on-Trent ST3 1HJ",
                        "Longitude": 2.1316,
                        "Latitude": 52.9878,
                        "icon": "bar"
                      },
                      "geometry": {
                        "coordinates": [
                          -2.131836,
                          52.987238
                        ],
                        "type": "Point"
                      }
                    },
```

Any help is much appreciated! thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly simple, you just need to build a feature array out of the Eventbrite response.

1. First build an array of geojson features to use in your source.
2. Then add the source to the map, separately and before you add the layer. You'll use the feature array you just created in the source.
3. After the source is added to the map you can create a layer and reference the source in your layer.

Try the code below to get you started. Let me know if it works for your case.

```js
var featureArr;
callbackEventbrite(function(result) {
  const keys = Object.values(result);
  for (const key of keys) {
    var feature = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": key.venue.id,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [key.venue.longitude, key.venue.latitude]
      },
      "properties": {
        "title": key.venue.name,
        "description": key.venue.description,
        "icon": "bar"
      }
    };
    featureArr.push(feature);
  }
}


map.addSource("mySource", {
  "type": "geojson",
  "data": {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": featureArr
  }
});

map.addLayer({
  "id": "locations",
  "type": "symbol",
  "source": "mySource",
  "layout": {
    "text-font": ["Open Sans Semibold", "Arial Unicode MS Bold"],
    "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
    "text-anchor": "top",
  }
});
```

Note: I don't know what's in the response object from Eventbrite so some of the `key.value.xyz` are made up variables

Comment: Thanks for the response! It seems to be the right approach, but I'm getting an error stating 'input data is not valid geoJSON object'.  I'm not sure why as the error doesn't give the line of code that is breaking.

Comment: I feel that one of the main issues here is that all data that is received from the API must be used within a callback. And for some reason, Mapbox doesn't seem to want to work when a layer or a source is being added within that callback

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. You are receiving data from their api that is no different than something you would hardcode. Maybe the datatype received from the api isn't being accepted as a valid coordinate or name. Can you update your question with an example response from eventbrite or your ajax call to eventbrite so that I can test it with a response?

Comment: @seanrs97 You can paste the generated geojson into http://geojson.io for better feedback on what's going right/wrong.